# Can I force Webpack to evaluate and inline a module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a JavaScript module:

```js
// lib/something-expensive.js
module.exports = theResultOfAnExpensiveCalculation()
```

I'm going to be running this code in a serverless environment, so if every invocation that calls `require('lib/something-expensive')` ends up calling `theResultOfAnExpensiveCalculation()` I'm going to add unnecessary latency and increase my server bill.

Is there a way to tell Webpack to evaluate `theResultOfAnExpensiveCalculation()` and compile the module to

```js
// lib/something-expensive.js
module.exports = "the result of the expensive calculation"
```

Comment: A `require`d module only runs the top-level code in the module *once*, no matter how many times that module is required

Comment: That's true, but it still has to run it. In a serverless environment, even that can add latency and cost quickly (since each invocation of the serverless function starts a new execution environment and has to require the module again).

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```js
// webpack.config.js

const webpack = require('webpack')
const expensiveThing = require('./lib/something-expensive')

module.exports = {
  // …
  plugins: {
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY': JSON.stringify(somethingExpensive),
    })
  }
}
```